# Repository Pattern Confusion

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern

```
public class CarRepository:IC
{ 
    public IRD ReferenceDataRepositry{get;set;}
    public string SaveCar(Car car)
    {
        //get data from reference data repository
    }
}

public class ReferenceDataRepository:IRD
{
   public string Get(string id)
   {

    }

}
```

When saving data in the repository, I want to get data from Reference data repository to set some of the properties.

Question is Should one repository know about other repository?
I am using dependency injection to set the reference data repository, should I be setting repositories inside repositories?

Answer (score 0):

you can, there DI simply states that an object depends on another, but is not responsible for instantiating the dependency.

however I would inject the read repo into the write repo. read and write are just that. get the object and save the object. there is still the responsibility of actually changing the object. this would happen in another component. like a controller action or service facade.

Answer (score 0):

I believe repositories should not know about each other. This additional behavior belongs to your service or business layer.

Repository pattern is all about decoupling your data access layer from the business layer and by coupling different repositories you letting your business logic to slip into data layer which is against the initial purpose of using this design pattern.

Btw. It is a good practice to separate method which are changing data from those which are reading them.

Answer (score 0):

The repository pattern as described [by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) is about encapsulation of logic and
how to separate the logic that retrieves the data and maps it to the entity model from the
business logic that acts on the model.

There should be no need to mix up different logics, each repository encapsulates one.

But if you need something like that, you can write an RepositoryManager class,
which handles the entangling between different Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I keep separated repositories for specific context. While a query repository is just reads, it usually serves the UI. A write repository, does have some reads too, but there are reads which serve the domain.

```
public interface DomainRepository
{
 Entity Get(int id);
 bool VerifySomeAspect();
 Save(Entity data);
}
```

See here how the DomainRepository features both reads and writes. As a principle, I wouldn't reuse another repository if it serves a different purpose.

Event if let's some method will be duplicate, then I make it internal and static, passing all the args it requires, but I wouldn't inject another repo. Probably in 95% of cases you don't need to do it if each repository has a clear responsibility and serves only one context.

This also means don't go with a generic repository.Design each repo, according to the layers/context needs and don't fall intro the trap of 'i should really re use as much as i can'. Reusing is good but tricky in this situation.